# I want to make a apps where people can upload their status,image or video what I need to know for this?

Tags: android

I want to make a apps where people can upload their status,image or video
what I need to know for this?

Comment: You need basic knowledge of android and knowledge of [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try using the FabeBook API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You would need the following:**

- API for the clients to connect to
- Database to store the information
- An Android client

**Develop your own API's**
You would need a server to host the API's and also register a domain. I use GoDaddy and they provide excellent service. But you could check out this site to help you decide on a service provider: http://www.webhostingbest10.com/

Next you need to decide on which language to use. I really like PHP. But you could also use Java or C# to develop your API's. This guide should get you started: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/tip/API-design-How-to-properly-build-an-application-program-interface

**Database**
You usually get a free MySQL database with your hosting. This can be used to create all the different tables required for the data. This should get you started: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx

**Client development**
After developing the API's and creating the required database tables. You can start developing the client application. Check out this guide: http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes

This should get you started with the basics of developing your application!

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: please help me to solve this problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385791/android-device-monitor-doesnt-open-in-android-studio-it-is-showing-the-error-wh