# android device monitor doesnt open in android studio ,it is showing the error which I have attach in below

Tags: java, android, image, device, monitor

[image]

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please post the content of the log file

Comment: the log file is too long...
doesnt allow to post too long post

Comment: my problem has been solve thank you for coming :)

Comment: Can you please post the answer to help people with the same issue

Comment: how to post answer sorry actually I dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running Android Studio as administrator and enable the Developer Mode in your device:

1. Go to your device settings.
2. Find the Android Build number in Settings
3. Tap on the section 7 times
4. After the 7th tap, the Developer options will be unlocked.

Allow USB debug mode and check the popup when the device is connected to the USB.

Comment: I tried but it shows empty

Comment: its now showing the box but empty

Comment: yes ,device is already in developer mood

Comment: Did you allow USB debug mode and did you check the popup when you connected the usb?

Comment: thank you soo much  :D  :D :*

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete the old log file
3. Run Android Studio as Administrator